# Why a 300x600 banner is being loaded in a 980x250 slot? Google DFP

Tags: google-dfp

Is there any explanation why a banner of 300x600 is being loaded on a 980x250 unit? This unit is set to display just 980x250 banners on Google DFP but on small resolutions the 980x250 banner is still being displayed and sometimes a 300x600 unit is displayed as well (however the tag being loaded is home_1_main_980_leader)

This is the header:

```
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var gptadslots = [];
  var googletag = googletag || {cmd:[]};
    </script>
    <script>
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {

      var mappingDesktop = googletag.sizeMapping().
          addSize([1280, 0], [[980, 250], [300, 250], [300, 600]] ). //bigger than 1280
          addSize([468, 0], [[728, 90], [300, 250], [300, 600]] ). //bigger than 468 but smaller than 1280
          addSize([320, 0], [[468, 60], [180, 150], [160, 600]] ). //bigger than 320 but smaller than 468
          addSize([0, 0], [320, 50]).
          build();

       googletag.defineSlot('/10039233/home_1_main_980_leader', [980, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-65')
      .defineSizeMapping(mappingDesktop)
      .setCollapseEmptyDiv(true)
      .addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/10039233/home_1_main_728_leader', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-143')
      .defineSizeMapping(mappingDesktop)
      .setCollapseEmptyDiv(true)
      .addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/10039233/home_1_main_468_leader', [468, 60], 'div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-221')
      .defineSizeMapping(mappingDesktop)
      .setCollapseEmptyDiv(true)
      .addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/10039233/home_1_main_320_leader', [320, 50], 'div-gpt-ad-1521131716762-0')
      .defineSizeMapping(mappingDesktop)
      .setCollapseEmptyDiv(true)
      .addService(googletag.pubads());

   googletag.enableServices();
});
```

and this is the body:

```
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-65' style='height:250px; width:980px;'>
    <!-- /10039233/home_1_main_980_leader -->
    <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-65'); });
    </script>
</div>

<div id='div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-143' style='height:90px; width:728px;'>
    <!-- /10039233/home_1_main_728_leader -->
    <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-143'); });
    </script>
</div>

<div id='div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-221' style='height:60px; width:468px;'>
    <!-- /10039233/home_1_main_468_leader -->
    <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-221'); });
    </script>
</div>

<div id='div-gpt-ad-1521131716762-0' style='height:50px; width:320px;'>
    <!-- /10039233/home_1_main_320_leader -->
    <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1521131716762-0'); });
    </script>
</div>
```

Any clue, please? I'll really appreciate any help you may give me to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, declared a 300x600 size on the home_1_main_980_leader ad slot ?

Answer (score 0):

Are all these slots on the same place in the site? Like one after another?

You are using the same size mapping (mappingDesktop) on all of your slots.
You need different size mapping for each slot. But if you want to have one place loading different sizes, it is different approach.

Your approach (probably) fixed. But on large desktop it will in fact render all of the 4 sizes (don't know if this is your goal or not?):

```
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var gptadslots = [];
  var googletag = googletag || {cmd:[]};
    </script>
    <script>
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {

      var leader1 = googletag.sizeMapping().addSize([980, 0], [980, 250]).addSize([0, 0], []).build // 1_main_980_leader
      var leader2 = googletag.sizeMapping().addSize([728, 0], [728, 90]).addSize([0, 0], []).build // 1_main_728_leader
      var leader3 = googletag.sizeMapping().addSize([468, 0], [468, 60]).addSize([0, 0], []).build // 1_main_468_leader
      var leader4 = googletag.sizeMapping().addSize([320, 0], [320, 50]).addSize([0, 0], []).build // 1_main_468_leader


       googletag.defineSlot('/10039233/home_1_main_980_leader', [980, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-65').defineSizeMapping(leader1).addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/10039233/home_1_main_728_leader', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-143').defineSizeMapping(leader2).addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/10039233/home_1_main_468_leader', [468, 60], 'div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-221').defineSizeMapping(leader3).addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/10039233/home_1_main_320_leader', [320, 50], 'div-gpt-ad-1521131716762-0').defineSizeMapping(leader4).addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
      googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
```

The example above will load 980x250 if width is 980 or bigger, 728x90 if width is 728 or bigger, 468x60 if width is 468 or bigger and 320x50 if width is 320 or bigger. It will not load any banner, if it is bellow 320.
And again, keep in mind this approach will load ALL 4 banners on width 980 or bigger.

If you want to have different sizes ON SINGLE PLACE depending on the size of the browser, you need only one ad unit and the code is much simple:

```
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var gptadslots = [];
  var googletag = googletag || {cmd:[]};
    </script>
    <script>
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {

      var leaderall = googletag.sizeMapping().addSize([980, 0], [980, 250]).addSize([728, 0], [728, 90]).addSize([468, 0], [468, 60]).addSize([320, 0], [320, 50]).addSize([0, 0], []).build // leaderall


      googletag.defineSlot('/10039233/home_1_main_980_leader', [[980, 250],[728, 90],[468x60],[320x50]], 'div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-65').defineSizeMapping(leaderall).addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
      googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
```

And in the body only:

```
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-65'>
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1521098852276-65'); });
</script>
</div>
```

Note 2 things:
1. In the body code the size of div is removed, so it doesn't "blinks" if there is no ad.
2. You don't need to have collapseEmptyDivs after each unit. Once is enough at the end.